# Deleting from Database

Tags: database, t-sql, executenonquery

I wrote a method to delete values from a database, however when I check the rows affected the value is 0 and keeps going into the first if statement any ideas?

```
     private void workstationDelete()
    {
        string query = "DELETE FROM test_revision2 where wsid = @wsid and location = '@location'";
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wsid", Convert.ToInt32(wsid2text.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", deletelocation);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            int rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (rowsaffected == 0)
            {
                lblDel.Text = "Sorry Workstation: " + wsid2text.Text + " does not exist in " + deletelocation + ". Therefore it cannot be removed.";
            }
            else
            {
                lblDel.Text = "You have successfully removed Workstation: " + Convert.ToInt32(wsid2text.Text) + " in " + deletelocation;
            }

            conn.Close();

        }

        catch (SqlException)
        {
            lblDel.Text = "randome";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotation marks from `'@location'`. You have it ignoring the parameter and trying to match a string literal.

Aside: There are [good reasons](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) not to use `AddWithValue`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using cmd.executeNonQuery twice the first one was returning 1 however when I initialized to a var it becomes 0. Use execute non query once - when assigning the int var.